# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: posts.user_id

Tags: database, laravel, sqlite, model-view-controller

I'm trying to create a create page where in a form an user text a caption and choose an image but whene i click a button to Add a New Post i get this error:

**SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: posts.user_id (SQL: insert into "posts" ("caption", "image", "updated_at", "created_at") values (asd, C:\xampp\tmp\phpB7DC.tmp, 2021-03-12 13:06:56, 2021-03-12 13:06:56))**

I want tell you that i'm using a sqlite db.

The Model of Post:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'caption', 'image',
    ];

    public function user() 
    {
        return $this->belognsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

The PostsController:

```
class PostsController extends Controller
{
    public function create() 
    {
        
        return view('posts.create');
    }

    public function store() {

        $data = request()->validate([
            'caption' => 'required',
            'image' => 'required|image',
        ]);

        \App\Post::create($data);
        dd(request()->all());
    }
}
```

My table post in migration folder:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->string('caption');
            $table->string('image');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->index('user_id');
        });
    }
```

Comment: You are not adding the user_id in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don`t send user_id value in your transaction

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id'); // this value must be set
        $table->string('caption');
        $table->string('image');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->index('user_id');
    });
}
```

In this part

```
class PostsController extends Controller
{
public function create() 
{
    
    return view('posts.create');
}

public function store() {

        $data = request()->validate([
            'caption' => 'required',
            'image' => 'required|image',
        ]);

        // In this section you must add user_id to data
        // For example
        $data['user_id'] = Auth::user()->id; 

        \App\Post::create($data);
        dd(request()->all());
    }
}
```

Comment: When you tell me that the user_id must be set what do you mean? It's not a foreign key connected to the user id table? And then how i can add to my $data variable in PostsController?

Comment: In your migration file user_id is not nullable. It is mean that you must set user_id each time when you created new record in table;

Answer (score 2):

in your migration, you didn't write this column Nullable.

you need to add `post_id` in your validations.

```
$data = request()->validate([
        'caption' => 'required',
        'image' => 'required|image',
        'post_id' => 'required|int'
    ]);
```